# Why does the bool tool remove entire object?

Tags: edit-mode

I am trying to create a hole by using the bool tool. However it is removing the whole object. Why is that?

Here is the file just in case: [image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: For some reason the Subdivision Surface modifier makes the boolean fail, so maybe disable it for the moment, select the boolean object (cylinder), shift the select the palette object and Shift Ctrl B and it works

Answer (score 3):

Because of the concave part of the object, the *Subdivision Surface* modifier creates some nasty geometry on the n-gon:

[image: bad geometry]

To get rid of that, you can simply select a vertex on the border of this concave part and one on the other side of the n-gon, then press <kbd>J</kbd> to connect them and split the face there:

[image: split face]

Repeat that on the backside of the object and the *Boolean Modifier* works as expected:

[image: boolean result]

Answer (score 2):

Boolean is the last resort to create holes, because it generally generates bad topology that you need to fix afterwards.

Here it looks like the *Subdivision Surface* of the palette makes the *Boolean* fail, so press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>-</kbd>, but move the *Boolean* modifier above the *Subdivision Surface*, apply the *Boolean*, fix the topology, reactivate the *Subdivision Surface*.

Here, I've created additional edges and I've bevelled the hole edges:

[image]

Comment: It works when I disable the subdivision, but when I able it again, I get a very weird shape for the cylinder. Because then it is also affecting that part of the object. It also does not make a difference when I apply the subdivision first

Comment: Because the Boolean creates a bad topology, so I'm not sure that you can fix that another way than to apply the Boolean modifier and fix the topology

Comment: @moonboots You can split the concave n-gon in two convex n-gons, then it works without a problem (see my answer).

Comment: Oh ok you're right

Comment: Ah these are great tips, thank you! But if you say boolean tool is not great to make holes. How would you make a hole like this in this case?

Comment: In your case it's ok because your object is rather simple  ;)

Answer (score 2):

just use "fast" as method -> this worked in my version

-> what also helps is to make a limited dissolve first, then inset after that

[image]

Comment: What do you mean fast as method?

Comment: in the boolean modifier -> you can choose fast or exact

Comment: When you use _Fast_ then you just have to bridge the border of the holes on front and back. At least when I downloaded the file, _Fast_ created open geometry.